# ways of making a communication between a webserver to a windows application in .NET

Tags: asp.net, c++, web-services, web

I need to find the most efficient way to communicate from an asp.net web server and a windows C++ application. The windows application does not have any permission to access the database of the asp.net web server.

When the user presses a button, that action with some bytes should be received by the C++ application.

In return, after processing the data on the C++ application, it will send back the result to the web server.

The only way I can think of at the moment is as following:

- The asp.net web server will have two web service methods:
- the C++ application will call that web service for a method for an interval. if there is a change, then the C++ application will process.
- after the C++ application finished its process, it will call a method on that web service to inform about the result.

Any other ways to solve this kind of communication?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the C++ Application is also on Windows, named pipes would be a good solution.  They can be configured to be durable so they can queue messages if either side is not ready to receive the  message and they are quite easy to use.  They basically look like files that you can read or write from and the data appears on the other side of the "pipe".

Take a look at the documentation (C++) here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365781(v=VS.85).aspx

On the ASP.NET side you would use .NET API's.  Here's a nice example to get you started: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546085.aspx (This example includes both client and server code.)

Named pipes would be a great solution if the C++ application is located in the same physical server as the ASP.NET application.  In that case the OS would be just moving memory between processes for you so it could be very quick.

Additionally, I would configure the C++ Application as a Windows Service so it's always available and can be restarted when the server it's running on is restarted.  If keeping it running is very important you could integrate Performance Counters and then have your ops team monitor the counters to make sure it is operating within expected thresholds.

Answer (score 1):

The C++ application can also make a simple **GET** or **POST** request with enough information that the webserver can handle in case you don't want to expose a webservice.

Comment: could you please give me some information how to call web service using get and post from C++ application

Answer (score 1):

You could use network sockets. It's been a long time since I have done anything with them so I can't be much help. Research Winsock (aka Windows Sockets API).

You could use WCF services and connect to them using your C++ client. You will have to research consuming WCF services from C++ client.

As @parapura suggested you could use simple HTTPRequest get & post methods. You could create your own http handler for these request to customize the response.

As you suggested you could use simple web services.